# point cloud produces meaningless data

Tags: ros, pcd, camera-depth-points, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to save the data that my TurtleBot sees when PointCloud2 is turned on. To do this I call 'rostopic echo /camera/depth/points > points.txt' but when I view the data it looks like the following:

header:

seq: 253

stamp:

```
secs: 1340030655

nsecs: 180170944
```

frame_id: camera_rgb_optical_frame

height: 480

width: 640

fields:

-

```
name: x

offset: 0

datatype: 7

count: 1
```

- name: y

  offset: 4

  datatype: 7

  count: 1
- name: z

  offset: 8

  datatype: 7

  count: 1

is_bigendian: False

point_step: 16

row_step: 10240

data: [0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 128, 63,

0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 128, 63,

0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 128, 63,

0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 128, 63,

.

.

.

0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 128, 63,]

Why does it give me the same point over and over again? When the data shows up in rviz it looks perfectly fine...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36723/point-cloud-produces-meaningless-data/) by [atmiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2640/atmiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rostopic echo`ing a PointCloud2 will not produce useful output in the data field. What you're seeing is a serialized format which is intended to be deserialized before use. If you want to save point cloud data for later you should use either [rosbag record](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record), which you can later play back as ROS messages, or [cloud_to_pcd](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd) which saves pcd files.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2